# child Routing in angular2 getting error

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

My Page Layout look like this one

```
-----------------------------------------------------
HEADER MENU --> Page1  <Page2>
-----------------------------------------------------
Page1 Child1 |
Page1 Child2 |       MAIN CONTENT
Page1 Child2 |
----------------------------------------------------
          FOOTER
----------------------------------------------------
```

if user click on Page1 i want to Refresh the Menus on the Left to list children for Page1, if i click Page 2 than i want to refresh the list of menu and display childrens of Pages 2

This is how my router look currently, but i am getting the error

```
core.umd.js:3070 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''
```

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError

index.html

```html
index.html

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
        <div class="col-md-10"><router-outlet name="main"><h2>Main Content Here</h2></router-outlet></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
app.module.ts


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Page1Component } from './Page1/Page1.component';
import { Page1Child1Component } from './Page1/Page1Child1/Page1Child1.component';
import { Page2Component } from './Page2/Page2.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,

            RouterModule.forRoot([
                { path: '', redirectTo: 'Page1', pathMatch: 'full' },
                {
                    path: 'Page1', component: Page1Component,
                    children: [
                        { path: '', redirectTo: 'Page1Child1', pathMatch: 'full' },
                        { path: 'Page1Child1', component: Page1Child1Component }
                    ]

                },
                { path: 'Page2', component: Page2Component }
            ])
        ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, Page1Component, Page2Component, Page1Child1Component],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

screenshot the UI looks as expected but there is error in the console window

```
core.umd.js:3070 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'Page1Child1Component'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'Page1Child1Component'
    at getOutlet
```

[image]

Page1.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'Page1',
    template: `<h1>This is from Page1 </h1>
    <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of links; let i = index">
        <a [routerLink]="['Page1Child1']" routerLinkActive="active" outlet:"main">{{item}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
   `
})
export class Page1Component {
    links: any[] = [
    'Page1 Child1',
    'Page1 Child2'
    ];

}
```

Now as soon as i update the Pag1Component to use named outlet it throws parsing error.

{{item}}

This just blows out the whole page and nothing is displayed, console window throws the parsing error

Error: (SystemJS) Template parse errors:(…)(anonymous function) @ (index):20ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:339

**Is there a better way of doing this**

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no root path in the children. When the `Page1` path first loads, it has a router outlet where it tries to load child routes, but with `Page1` there is a route configured with `''`. This would be required when you go to the `Page1` url. If you went to `Page1/Page1Child1`, it knows the component, but `Page1` (which would need to map to `''`) doesn't exist

So just add a redirect to the default child route

```
children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'Page1Child', pathMatch: 'full' }
  { path: 'Page1Child1', component: Page1Child1Component}
]
```

Comment: core.umd.js:3070 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError still getting the error, still don't understand why do i need to give empty route, i want to display all the children for Page1 when user clicks page1, and don't want to navigate to Page1Child1. only navigate to that explicitly when user clicks on the hyperlink from displayed menu.

Comment: To use `children` for `Page1Component`, you need a router-outlet in that component. This is how `children` works. And if you have a router-outlet in the `Page1Child1Component` then it need s default route when you navigate to `/Page`. If you don't want `Page1Child1Component` to have its own router-outlet, then don't use `children`. Just add the route `/Page1/Page1Child` to root routing, without using `children` for the `Page1` route

Comment: You can have a component that for the path `''` (instead of redirecting) if you want, that shows all the children.